# jQuery UI tabs loading first as <ul> then as tabs

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI and the tab control on a series of pages.
It seems like, when loading a page, the tabs initially load as a simple list, then they jump to the tabstrip.

When I initially load the page I get this:
[image]

Then, after a few seconds it switches over to this (the way is should be):
[image]

Any idea why this is happening?  Do I need to load the .js and/or .css files in a particular order?  Or, is there a way to hide the initial list and only display the tabs once they are 'loaded'?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This happens because you call $('#id').tabs() in document.ready(), which happens when the DOM is ready to be traversed<sup>[[1](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready#fn)]</sup>. This generally means the page has been rendered, and so the `<ul>` is visible on the page as a regular `<ul>` without any tab-specific styling applied.

It's not super "clean", but a way I use to get around this is to add the `ui-tabs` class to the `<ul>` in the HTML, which causes it to get the CSS style applied immediately. The downside is that you don't have the 100% clean separation of behaviour and code, but the upside is it looks nice.

Comment: I'm just using
    $(function() {
        $("#tabstrip").tabs({ });
        $("#insiteTABs").tabs( 'select' , 1 )
    }); 
Should I being doing something different?

Comment: No, just add the classes: `<div class="ui-tabs"><ul class="ui-tabs-nav">`, and potentially the ui-widgets* classes- it's best to use firebug and inspect the element after its rendered, and add all those classes to your HTML.

Comment: Thanks...I'm going this direction.

Comment: Just to add another suggestion. You can also set the tabs container to display:none(or visibility:hidden in some cases) and then set it to visible when the jQuery tabs call is finished. Though, keep in mind that for slower loading pages the tabs won't be usable until the page has completed loading.

Comment: +1 That's very clever and easy to implement solution. Note,I am using the "jquery-ui-1.8.24" version and I needed to add few more classes.

Answer (score 24):

Like others have said, it's because jQuery doesn't render the `UL` as tabs until the document has loaded. I've gotten around this problem by simply hiding the tabs until they're loaded. That way you get rid of the flicker. For instance:

```
<ul id="tabs" style="display: none;">
...
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#tabs').tabs();
  $('#tabs').attr('display', 'block');
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, u saved my time.. But i need to change one place, $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#tabs').tabs();
  $('#tabs').css('display', 'block');
});

Comment: Good idea. Slight adjustment - put the #tabs {display:none} in your CSS, and use $("#tabs").tabs().show();

Answer (score 1):

This is normal, but it shouldn't take a few seconds. How much are you doing in your jQuery ready (AKA `$()`) function before you call `$("#whatever").tabs()`? Try moving that method call to the top of your ready function.

Comment: Now that I really look at it and time it out it is more like 1 second or so (it just seems longer) - maybe I should not be so concerned...?

Comment: If it bothers you, you can do what James Skidmore suggests and hide it, but you'll still have to deal with it suddenly appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I am not sure whether this is right way but I used the following hack. (I tried other answers, and they are not working for me).

First I just used following code for anchor tag:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul >
        <li style="list-style-image: none !important; list-style-type: none"><a href="#tabs-1" id="link1" ></a></li>
        <li style="list-style-image: none !important; list-style-type: none"><a href="#tabs-2" id="link2" ></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In Document ready function I wrote following (jQuery) code to name the Anchor tags using:

```
$("#link1").text('Current');
$("#link2").text('Archived');
```

Comment: Thanks !! - For all those facing issues with IE , need this style="list-style-image: none !important; list-style-type: none"

Answer (score 1):

Hide the main `div` by default:

```
<div id="tabs" style="display: none;">
```

Then in the end of document where your script is, just remove the style:

```
<script>
    $("#tabs").removeAttr('style');
    $("#tabs").tabs();   
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was to set the `display` style property to `none` for the `div` element that contains the tabs and then call the `show()` method after the `tabs()` method.

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    $( "#tabs" ).show();
  } );
</script>

<div class="tabbody" id="tabs" style="display: none;">
    <!-- tab html -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. The page where I had defined the tabs had missed importing the jquery-ui css.

Html code :

```
 <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li>
             <a href="connectionDetailsTab1.html?name=<%=  jmsConnectionName %>">Summary</a>

         </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

The anchor's href has the jquery-ui css imported, because of which the tabs were showing up correctly, after the tabs get loaded. But , before that, it was showing a ul without the tab specific styling. Fix was to import the jquery-ui css in the above html too. jquery-ui version used : 1.10.2

Answer (score -1):

I'm using the jQuery UI tabs with great success. Here's some code I use:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">
            <span>Applicant</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="">
            <span>Insured</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="">
            <span>Beneficiary</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="">
            <span>Billing</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="">
            <span>Summary</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
            disabled: [1, 2, 3, 4],
            event: null,
            load: function(event, ui) {
                handleload(ui);
            },
            selected: 0
        });
    });

</script>
```

As for the order I always place the jquery-ui.css first, followed by jquery.min.js and jquery-ui.min.js. I'm using the latest versions (jQuery 1.3.2 and jQuery 1.7.2) all served from the Google CDN.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the css from jquery-ui is for the classes that the jquery-ui script add to the DOM when the page has loaded. Rather then adding ui-tabs to the HTML (as suggested by gregmac) you could simply add the same `display` rules to your CSS to apply to your navbar id. When jqueryui adds the classes to the `ul` and list items, the jqueryui CSS takes over.

So add this rule to your css:

```
#navbarID li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: I like the results of that change except it makes any <li> inside of the tab container display inline as well...  I might have to workaround that...